# Unix timestamp from csv gives me the same date, although different values

Tags: excel, csv, unix, timestamp

I have a csv file with some columns, like date and time. The date is a 10 digit format, unix format from what i read online. 
examples are: 1567285228,1567285348, 1567371053.I found that I can use the formula: =(((A2/60)/60)/24)+DATE(1970,1,1) to calculate the proper date from the code, but the problem is that my csv is for one entire month, the codes are different, but the proper date gives me only 2 values: 01 sept 2019 and 31 aug 2019.
How can I find the REAL dates, for the WHOLE month?

Also, the time when the measurements are taken are for example: 712980, 713040
,713100,713160, but when i use excel to format the time stamp to proper time, it only shows me 12 AM. How can I calculate the proper dates and time, so that I can analyse the data from the csv?

Comment: It's not clear what your "time" values represent?

Comment: Your date conversion is correct, so if you only see two dates that's because those are the only dates in your file (assuming your formulas are all set up correctly).  If your "Time" values are seconds since midnight, then 712980 (eg) gives me 6:03AM

Comment: hopefully you can do a data validation like `awk -F, '{print $3}' myCopy| sort | uniq -c` to know what the distribution of your date/time values are. (Change $3 to what ever field contains the date/time of interest). Oh, make a copy of  your file and then `dos2unix myCopy`. before the running the pipeline. If you get each record as a count of 1, then you may have to do some math to truncate/round up/down to get just the date value (without any time messing it up). Good luck.